# Git hard reset just move HEAD

Tags: git

I'm trying to remove 5 published commit from my git doing a hard reset to my specific commit.

The thing is that Sourcetree warns me, but it just move the HEAD.

So, basically, if I pull changes again, I recover my changes.

Also, I can't make changes, because I would have to pull changes first.

This is agains what I believed about hard reset; I thought it was the only "destructive" operation in Git.

Is there an alternative to this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to destroy things about the upstream repository, you need to run `git push -f` to make its branch point to a different commit.

Beware that that will break anyone else who pulls.

Comment: Just to add to SLaks's answer, there is a fundamental principle in git that everything you do affects only your local repo, unless you invoke `git fetch` or `git push` (understanding that `git pull` is just `git fetch` + merge or rebase). So unless you're running one of those commands, you will not affect the upstream. Not understanding this is missing something very fundamental about how git works.

Comment: @Major Good point. I should have that git fetch/push "involve" (rather than "affect") the upstream.